# How To handel CTRL+S keypress event in Extjs 3.4

Tags: extjs

I want to create shortcut key  for save.i have written the following code but its not overriding browsers default shortcut keys.

This is my Code

```
Ext.getDoc().on('keypress' function(event, target) {
                                            if (event.ctrlKey && event.S) {
                                                        event.preventDefault();
                                                        this.save();
                                                    }
                                                }
                                        });
```

Comment: It depends on the browser, some won't let you override "built in" hotkeys like that, since they have a meaning for the browser itself.

Answer (score 1):

```
new Ext.KeyMap( Ext.getBody(), [{
            key: "s",
            ctrl:true,
            fn: function( e, ele ){
                ele.preventDefault();
                //implement your logic
            }
        }]);
```

put this code in launch function of your application.